# React-native storybook without dev. server

Tags: react-native, production, storybook, devserver

I am using the react-native storybook. (https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native#storybook-for-react-native). 
With some dev. server there is a nice overview for the storybook. My question is: 
**Is it possible to render the react-native storybook in the app without any dev. server.? 
 If yes, how?**

Comment: Your question could be clearer. Dev server is necessary to compile. Can you adjust your question so that it is clearer?

Comment: did you check my answer. stackoverflow.com/a/63535376/8079868

Answer (score 2):

**yes,** you can render the react-native storybook in the app without any webpack dev server

you need to install `@storybook/react-native` package and follow the [Docs](https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native)

here is an example project: https://github.com/nomi9995/expo-storybook-boilerplate.git

1. clone above boilerplate
2. install node_modules by `yarn` or `npm install`
3. run storybook app by `yarn start` or `expo start`
4. then press `i` to open app on `ios` simulator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you think you want to list and display the components created in a web view, so that it is shareable without running the app in dev mode, you should look for storybook server option.

https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/blob/master/app/react-native/readme.md